# Limit of double integral is integral of boundary.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, fourier-series

Working on a preparing for a preliminary exam, came across the following question.

For $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\ \mathbb{R}^2$, let $\vert x\vert=(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}$. Let $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}; \vert x\vert<1\}$, and let $f:\bar{D}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\bar{D}$. Prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\iint_D(n+2)\vert x\vert^nf(x)\,dA=\int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)) \, d\theta.$$

Since the domain is a circle, I used the polar transform to end up with

\begin{align}
& \iint_D(n+2)\vert x\vert^n f(x)\,dA \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (n+2) r^n f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)) \cdot r\,dr\,d\theta \\
= {} & \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1(n+2)r^{n+1}f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)) \, dr\,d\theta
\end{align}

Since the form $(n+2)r^{n+1}$ seems like it is begging to be integrated, I began to use integration by parts, but then realized there are no differentiability assumptions about $f$. I also thought about uniform limit theorems with $f_n(r,\theta)=(n+2)r^{n+1}f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$, but the pointwise limit isn't continuous.

A step in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $dA ?dx_1dx_2$?

Comment: Not included in the question, but I am assuming so.

Comment: I think your instincts are good, as a Fourier series approach doesn't seem to go anywhere. Since $C^1$ functions are dense in $C^0$, why not follow your instincts and do the integration by parts? Not quite sure how it finishes up, though.

Comment: Integration by parts *does* work fine, but you need to use $C^2$ dense in $C^0$. But the accepted answer is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid integration by parts. Let
$$ \Delta(r,\theta) = f(\cos \theta,\sin \theta) - f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).$$

Use compactness to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $r_\epsilon<1$ so that $|\Delta(r,\theta)| <\epsilon$ for every $r_\epsilon<r\leq 1$ and uniformly in $\theta$.
Use this to estimate  $\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} (n+2)r^{n+1}\Delta(r,\theta) d\theta\; dr $ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: This works so easily, thank you for the insight.

Comment: @H. H. Rugh Where are we using compactness? In order to use polar coordinates, we're using a coordinate chart right? If we're using $\varphi:(0,2\pi) \times (0,1) \to D$, $(r,\theta) \mapsto (r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$, how are we even using continuity at $1$, which kinda seems is what you're getting at? Are we picking another coordinate chart that includes $1$ in it's domain?